# Saving a file from FileResult as a pdf is not working consistently

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf-generation

**Overview**

I am converting html to pdf in my ASP.NET Core web application using SelectPdf library for .NET.

I have 2 scenarios where I "print to pdf" that will take some html I provide and generated a pdf file by returning a `FileResult`.

Here is an example that is working:

```
<form asp-action="PrintLoanFilePdf" asp-controller="Lender" 
      asp-route-id="@Model.LoanFileId" method="post">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
            style="margin-top:10px;" value="Print" />
</form>
```

In the controller method below, I get a byte array called 'pdf' from `ConvertHtmlString()` `doc.Save()`. The byte array 'pdf' shows byte data as expected.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PrintLoanFilePdf(string id)
{
    try
    {
        // ...getting  some data and html here...

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
        byte[] pdf = doc.Save();
        doc.Close();

        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = $"Loan-File.pdf";

        return fileResult;
    }
    catch (HtmlToPdfException ex)
    {
        // ...handle exception...
    }
}
```

In the code above I get a `FileResult` returned, and the pdf opens in the browser.

Now, the below code should do the same thing. The controller method is executed from Javascript this time:

```
<input type="button" id="printToPdf" onclick="printToPdf('edit')" 
       class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin-top:10px; float:right;" value="PDF" />
```

```
//print letter to pdf
function printToPdf(printFrom) {
    if (printFrom == "edit") {
        var id = $("#letterId").val();
    }
    else {
        var id = $("#letterROId").val();
    }
    closeLetter();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Lender/PrintLetterPdf/" + id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json"
            });

    jqxhr.done(function (data) {
        printingPdf();
    });

    jqxhr.fail(function () {
        var msg = "An error occurred while printing Letter PDF!";
        ShowInfoMessage(msg, 'error');
    });
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PrintLetterPdf(string id)
{
    try
    {
        // ...getting  some data and html here...

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html);
        byte[] pdf = doc.Save();
        doc.Close();

        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
        fileResult.FileDownloadName = $"Loan-Application.pdf";

        return fileResult;
    }
    catch (HtmlToPdfException ex)
    {
        // ...handle exception...
    }
}
```

This code however returns a byte array called pdf just like the first example, however, the `FileResult` returns no file and the method completes with no exception.

I cannot identify why this would be happening in code that is almost identical...

Comment: the difference is that the file is being returned to the script callback.  Then you call "printingPdf();" which does ?? and nothing is done with "data" (your fileResult).  You should probably not use ajax at all there... just let the controller return the file directly to the browser.  The ajax is also calling "/Lender/PrintLetterPdf/"... which controller does that go to?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking maybe I should not use ajax...

Comment: Put your comment into an answer and I will make it as such

Comment: it'd probably be better if you answer your own question here.  (SO does allow that...)  Then you can post the revised code or specific solution.